# Form echo is not applied of first item in a list

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a list with custom post type and I added additional fields with a status, coming from a meta value and a button, in order to toggle the status. The code does work without issues and toggles between online and offline meta value. However, I experienced that the form tags are not applied on the first item in the list. When I expect the code I see for the first item only the hidden input field and the submit button. Can you please support me to get it fixed. Here is the code, which is creating both columns

```
function my_manage_portfolio_columns( $column, $post_id ) {
    global $post;

    switch( $column ) {

        /* If displaying the 'status' column. */
        case 'status' :

            /* Get the post meta value. */
            $status = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_status_visible', true );

            /* If status is online */
            if ( $status == "online" )
                echo '<span class="badge_green">'.$status.'</span>';

            /* If there is a duration, append 'minutes' to the text string. */
            else
                echo '<span class="badge_red">'.$status.'</span>';



            break;

        /* If displaying the 'change button' column. */
        case 'change' :
        echo '<form action="" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="'.$post_id.'">
                <input type="submit" class="button action" name="submit_btn" value="Change">
                </form>';

            break;

        /* Just break out of the switch statement for everything else. */
        default :
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you want from us? your question is still not clear

Comment: Ok sorry if was not clear. My question is why the echo not the full echo is outputed to the first item in a list. I'm using a list on admin side, which displays all related cpt

Comment: did you try `die;` after echo `form` text ?

Comment: I tried and then only 1 item is populated in the list

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using wrong implementation of manage posts custom column API. It should be like this:

CPT: my_portfolio

```
add_action( 'manage_my_portfolio_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_my_portfolio_column', 10, 2 );
function custom_my_portfolio_column( $column, $post_id ) {
     switch( $column ) {

        /* If displaying the 'status' column. */
        case 'status' :

            /* Get the post meta value. */
            $status = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_status_visible', true );

            /* If status is online */
            if ( $status == "online" )
                echo '<span class="badge_green">'.$status.'</span>';

            /* If there is a duration, append 'minutes' to the text string. */
            else
                echo '<span class="badge_red">'.$status.'</span>';



            break;

        /* If displaying the 'change button' column. */
        case 'change' :
        echo '<form action="" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="'.$post_id.'">
                <input type="submit" class="button action" name="submit_btn" value="Change">
                </form>';

            break;


    }
}
```

Also read this for detail information: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column

Comment: Thank you for your help. however, I have still same issue.

Comment: Can you share the admin CPT screen with having inspect element targeted to your expected form element? Also please share your actual code as you have written in functions.php file.